# What is wrong with the parameters list in this GCC inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to embed the following assembly instruction (of an ARM-like architecture) using GCC's extended asm syntax:

```
__asm__("lsr  %[xj], %[xj], %[xn]" : 
            [xj] "=r" (j) : 
            [xi] "[xj]" (j) , [xn] "[xn]" (n)); // j = j >> n
```

`i`, `j`, and `n` are declared as integers `int i, j, n;`

(note that `j` serves as both *in* and *out* parameter)

The compiler generates the error:

```
../src/fft2dlib.c:55:5: error: matching constraint references invalid operand number
../src/fft2dlib.c:53:3: error: matching constraint references invalid operand number
```

where lines 53 and 55 are the first and third lines of the above asm code.

When I replace the `n` input parameter with an explicit constant in the assembly instruction, it compiles fine:

```
__asm__("lsr  %[xj], %[xj], 27" : 
            [xj] "=r" (j) : 
            [xi] "[xj]" (j)); // j = j >> 27
```

I am following examples from the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), but I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contraint `"[xn]"` in `[xn] "[xn]" (n)` doesn't really make sense. Using a parameter name or number as a constraint means "put this operand in the same location as the named operand". So in this case you're telling GCC to put `[xn]` in the same location as `[xn]`, which is meaningless and doesn't actually give information about the operand type.

You need to use another constraint type, such as `"r"` for a register operand, depending on what the assembly instruction allows.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand this correctly, the `"[xj]"` of the second parameter (the `xi`) only compiles b/c `[xj]` was previously defined as `"=r"`? That makes sense. But then, if you look at the manual page I linked to, there is an example (following the text "As of GCC version 3.1") where the `old` variable is assigned the constraint `"[result]"` w/o this being defined by a type previously. How does this work?

Comment: As of GCC version 3.1, one may write [name] instead of the operand number for a matching constraint. For example:

     `asm ("cmoveq %1,%2,%[result]"
          : [result] "=r"(result)
          : "r" (test), "r"(new), "[result]"(old));`

Comment: OOOPPPSSS... my mistake - I failed to see the instance of `result` in the output list.